# Adding employee phone from form to table

Tags: angular

I have this template

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

  <div formArrayName="phones">

      <div *ngFor="let phone of phoneForms.controls; let i=index" 
            [formGroupName]="i">

          <input formControlName="area">
          <input formControlName="prefix">
          <input formControlName="line">

          <button (click)="deletePhone(i)">Delete</button>

      </div>
  </div>

  <button (click)="addPhone()">Add Phone Number</button>

</form>
```

and this is the controller code

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    email: '',
    phones: this.fb.array([])
  })

}

get phoneForms() {
  return this.myForm.get('phones') as FormArray
}

addPhone() {

  const phone = this.fb.group({ 
    area: [],
    prefix: [],
    line: [],
  })

  this.phoneForms.push(phone);
}

deletePhone(i) {
  this.phoneForms.removeAt(i)
}
```

[This how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avc6F.png)

But i want to show form fields only once and what ever the phone no we add should be shown below in data table or normal table with edit and delete button such that if edit is clicked that particular data gets populated in the fields above

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: This question is not clear, it is impossible to give an answer, and it is unlikely that editing will improve it to an acceptable level. Please write your question again, and show us what you tried, and what went wrong. You can then remove this question.

Comment: Your edited question makes sense to me now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could achieve the desired functionality like this:

- in addition to your editable template, make a readonly version
- with ngIf, always show the readonly version except when the current phone is being edited
- to keep track which phone is being edited, just use a local variable (e.g. the index of the phone or an ID if available)
- of course the local variable would be set via an edit button that you put in the readonly template

Does this make sense? I guess you don't need example code for this, it looks kind of straight forward?

Good luck!